# Getting a certificate from an https site

Tags: macos, ssl, https, vpn

I need to get the site certificate for my company's vpn site, so I can use it to set up the cisco client built in to OS X.

I can expand the certificate under the lock icon in Chrome and Safari, but I can't extract it from there. 
I tried searching through Keychain Access, and it's not in there. The certificate is under the Go Daddy CA, in the browser, but there's no way to expand that in Keychain to get the derived certificates.

Any suggestions on how to get a copy of this certificate (or even just the public key it contains)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox has the ability to download them. Expose it the same way, then choose export.

Answer (score 2):

You can also export in Chrome, click on the lock, select connection tab, select certification information, select details and then button "copy to file". Really easy to find!

Regards,
Vasilij

Comment: Thanks! How to get there is slightly different in the latest Chrome versions, but the first and last few steps are the same. It's now: Click on the lock -> Click the "details" link at the top (which will open the Security Tab) -> Click on the "View certificate" button -> Select the "Details" tab -> Click on the "Copy to File..." button.

Answer (score 0):

Its usually really easy.
I don't use these browsers but in IE it has in the second tab (of the displayed certificate)  the option `Copy to File` and you can save it as `der` or `pem`. In firefox in the `View Certificate`->`Details` tab there is an `Export Button`.

Answer (score -2):

Use portecle tool ....Click option examin ssl and give your host name and try to save the pem ...you will get the certifi